# if statements possibly not working

Tags: android

I have a fairly simple calculator with 2 tabs, the tabs appear to be working fine with the first tab calculating as it should, but the calculating for the second tab keeps throwing the **catch error**.

In the 2nd tab, I have 2 if statements, which checks to see which edittext field contains data. Depending on which contains data to what calculation it does.

Below is the code for when my button is pressed I have put together, it could probably be streamlined but just I'm an amature so go easy on me.

Any advice to get this working please?

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    if ( tabs.getCurrentTab() == 0) {

                        try {

                            if (d.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {


                                a1 = a.getText().toString();
                                double a2 = Double.parseDouble(a1);

                                b1 = b.getText().toString();
                                double b2 = Double.parseDouble(b1);

                                double sum = (a2 * b2) / 10000;

                                double total = Math.round((sum) * 10) / 10.0;

                                answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                                answer.setText(String.valueOf("Total Area Allocation = " + total + " ha"));

                            } else if (d.getText().toString().trim().length() >= 1) {

                                a1 = a.getText().toString();
                                double a2 = Double.parseDouble(a1);

                                b1 = b.getText().toString();
                                double b2 = Double.parseDouble(b1);


                                d1 = d.getText().toString();
                                double d2 = Double.parseDouble(d1);


                                double sum = (a2 * b2) / 10000;
                                double sum2 = (a2 * b2) / d2;

                                double total = Math.round((sum) * 10) / 10.0;
                                double total2 = Math.round((sum2) * 10) / 10.0;

                                answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                                answer.setText(String.valueOf("Total Area Allocation = " + total + " ha"));
                                answer2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                                answer2.setText(String.valueOf("Set break " + total2 + " m"));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                            answer.setText("Enter values in input fields");
                        }
                    }

                    if (tabs.getCurrentTab() == 1) {

                        try {

                            if (ff.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {


                                aa1 = aa.getText().toString();
                                double aa2 = Double.parseDouble(aa1);

                                bb1 = bb.getText().toString();
                                double bb2 = Double.parseDouble(bb1);

                                cc1 = cc.getText().toString();
                                double cc2 = Double.parseDouble(cc1);

                                dd1 = dd.getText().toString();
                                double dd2 = Double.parseDouble(dd1);

                                ee1 = ee.getText().toString();
                                double ee2 = Double.parseDouble(ee1);


                                if (ee.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){

                                    double sum = (aa2 * bb2)/(cc2 - dd2);

                                    double total = Math.round((sum) * 10) / 10.0;

                                    answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                                    answer.setText(String.valueOf("Total Area Allocation = " + total + " ha"));

                                }

                                else if (cc.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){

                                    double sum = (aa2 * bb2)/ee2;

                                    double total = Math.round((sum) * 10) / 10.0;

                                    answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                                    answer.setText(String.valueOf("Total Area Allocation = " + total + " ha"));

                                }


                            } else if (ff.getText().toString().trim().length() >= 1) {

                                aa1 = aa.getText().toString();
                                double aa2 = Double.parseDouble(aa1);

                                bb1 = bb.getText().toString();
                                double bb2 = Double.parseDouble(bb1);

                                cc1 = cc.getText().toString();
                                double cc2 = Double.parseDouble(cc1);

                                dd1 = dd.getText().toString();
                                double dd2 = Double.parseDouble(dd1);

                                ee1 = ee.getText().toString();
                                double ee2 = Double.parseDouble(ee1);

                                ff1 = ff.getText().toString();
                                double ff2 = Double.parseDouble(ff1);

                                if (ee.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){

                                    double sum = (aa2*bb2)/(cc2-dd2);
                                    double sum2 = (sum * 10000) / ff2;

                                    double total = Math.round((sum) * 10) / 10.0;
                                    double total2 = Math.round((sum2) * 10) / 10.0;


                                    answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                                    answer.setText(String.valueOf("Total Area Allocation = " + total + " ha"));
                                    answer2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                                    answer2.setText(String.valueOf("Set break " + total2 + " m"));

                                }

                                else if (cc.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){

                                    double sum = (aa2 * bb2)/ee2;
                                    double sum2 = (sum * 10000) / ff2;

                                    double total = Math.round((sum) * 10) / 10.0;
                                    double total2 = Math.round((sum2) * 10) / 10.0;

                                    answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                                    answer.setText(String.valueOf("Total Area Allocation = " + total + " ha"));
                                    answer2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                                    answer2.setText(String.valueOf("Set break " + total2 + " m"));

                                }

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            answer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
                            answer.setText("Enter values in input fields 2");
                        }


                    }
                }


            });
```

[image: The Catch error]

Comment: Can you post the error that is thrown?

Comment: can you post the exception message you are getting? Use Log.d("Error",e.getMessage()) in catch block.

Comment: Agreed that stacktrace is needed. And yes, generally it's not a good practise to catch just an `Exception`, because God (and Jon Skeet) knows how can your code fail. Catch separate exceptions instead and handle them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that. Handy to know.D/Error: empty String

Comment: It sounds like one of your `Double.parseDouble( String )` is causing the issue. I would suggest refactoring your code to help reduce duplication, and handle those cases better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not strictly on topic of why you're running into the exceptions, might I make some suggestions to help improve your code and hopefully reduce problems down the road.

1. Try to use more helpful variable names, it's hard to know what `aa` and `bb` actually are. Try to explain what they actually contain. `numOfCows` or what have you.
2. Move your logic into smaller functions. This will help you understand at a glance what the code does, and what other code it calls.

For example, create functions for handling each tab's calculation, and move that logic into there.

```
 calculate.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (tabs.getCurrentTab() == 0) {
                        calculateFirstTab();
                    } else if (tabs.getCurrentTab() == 1) {
                        calculateSecondTab();
                    }
                }
            });
```

3. And lastly, try to reduce duplication. You have a lot of code that does the same thing, but you can make it a lot cleaner by creating small functions to help.

For example, here I have created a function called `setAnswer` that lets me pass in a TextView, and some text. This will let you set the background color is one place, and update the text. Then, creating another function called `setAnswers` that lets you pass in the totals, you can now set both answers just like that.

```
private void setAnswers( double total1, double total2 ){
    setAnswer(answer, "Total Area Allocation = " + total1 + " ha");
    setAnswer(answer2, "Set break " + total2 + " m");
}

private void setAnswer( TextView view, String text  ) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d6ffffff"));
    view.setText(text);
}
```

There are definitely a lot of other ways to improve, but just some suggestions that may help you out.

Comment: All sorted now, and much cleaner code. Thanks again

Comment: That's great to hear. Keep that in mind while going forward and it'll definitely make your life easier.